# Running Ora2Pg with PostgreSQL 14

Tags: perl, database-connection, cpan, ora2pg, postgresql-14

I've got **PostgreSQL v14** server to migrate data from old Oracle server using **ora2pg** tool *version 22.1*.

There is a problem when i try to execute `ora2pg -c properties.conf`, that gives me the following output:

> [========================>] 2/2 tables (100.0%) end of scanning.
> DBI connect('dbname=postgres;host=hostname;port=5432','username',...) failed: authentication method 10 not supported at C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/Ora2Pg.pm line 2100.
> FATAL: 1 ... authentication method 10 not supported
> Aborting export...

As i did some research, i know that `authentication method 10` is probably a **SCRAM authentication method**, that is default for PostgreSQL 14.

I've tried to install a perl package `Authen::SCRAM` with `cpan`, but im not familiar with the perl programming and that did not helped me.

The questions are:

- is there a way to enable `authentication method 10` in ora2pg?
- if so, how do i do that?

Comment: I guess this is the tool you're talking about - https://ora2pg.darold.net/. It would have been nice to have been given a link in your question.

Comment: I suspect you'll get better help with this question by posting it on the [Ora2Pg issue tracker](https://github.com/darold/ora2pg/issues).